# Post variables from "pay page" and get in the "return page" in PHP

Tags: paypal

I have created a paypal button (using button editor).

I need post 3 values when an user click the button and when the user's pay is accepted, I need put those values in the url http:.../?var1=asdasd&var2=fdsgsdfg&var3=ggfg

Is it posible using button generator or I need create a button?

(sorry for my bad english and thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You have button generator at PayPal's site it will add all variables you need for button:

https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside

click on link 'create your button now' you should be logged in to see all features